# How to get the content of a div that uses Angular js binding?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to get the content of a div that contains angular scope bound data.

```
<div id='someDiv'> <h1> {{someText}} </h1> </div>
```

where in the controller,

```
$scope.someText = 'Hello World';
```

The innerHtml property does not work. document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHtml does not work as it returns the unbound variable

var content =  document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHtml;
console.log(content);

results in logging  `<h1> {{someText}} </h1>`

**I want it to return the div content after variable is bound to it's value like so `'<h1> Hello World! </h1>'`**

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You are probably trying to get the value too early before even angular has a chance to process it. `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML` and try wrapping it in timeout. `setTimeout(function(){ console.log(document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHtml); });` http://jsbin.com/lodazaxose/4/edit

Comment: You might need to wait until angular's digest cycle finishes. Simply doing it on a setTimeout() might not be enough.

Comment: @PSL, thanks, your comment and fiddle illustrates the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the $timeout service in angular. Might a well create a directive to pull out the HTML as there is no sure way to know when a digest cycle is done when outside of angular.

Here is an example of such a directive:

```
module.directive('getRenderedHtml', function($timeout) {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope) {
            return {};
        },
        requires: 'getRenderedHtml',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, thisController) {
            var rawHtmlContainer = angular.element('<div></div>');
            $timeout(function() {
                thisController.html = element[0].innerHTML;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rnpn8rj0/

Comment: thanks, the directive example is great. How would you modify the directive to access the rendered html through  a variable from within the controller?

Comment: That answer depends on where / how you plan on using the HTML. Storing the data in a controller does not seem right. If you need the data in multiple different places in the app it would make more sense to store the data in a Service. Alternatively you could store the data in the controller of the directive although then only child directives could use it but it would also be available for use in the HTML directly.